# Easier way to implement .cpp file

Tags: c++

Im just curious, but is there a way to make it so you don't have to put a class name before a function?  here's an example:

HelloWorld.h

```
class HelloWorld{
    HellowWorld();
};
```

HelloWorld.cpp

```
#include "HellowWorld.h"

HelloWorld::HelloWorld(){}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to be able to have the .cpp file look like the following.

HelloWorld.cpp  < New Version

```
#include "HellowWorld.h"

HelloWorld(){}
```

Comment: Yes, you can have functions which are not members of any class, but you need to give non-constructor/destructor functions return types. (e.g. `void HelloWorld(){}`)

Comment: Yes, you can use free functions if it doesn't make sense to use a class. If it's in a class, though, you need to specify that. You could easily have a function outside of the class also called `HelloWorld` (or whatever member functions the class has).

Comment: OP clearly specified the condition: class HelloWorld{
    HellowWorld();
};

Comment: I'm very confused.  Are you talking about class constructors, static methods in a class, or free standing functions?  Free standing functions don't require a `class`, `struct` or `union`; very similar to the C language function declarations and definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions do not have to be defined in the class, only declared.

I prefer to define the method contents in a separate file.  This reduces the chance of other files compiling because I made a change to the content of a function.

Hello.hpp:

```
  class HelloWorld
  {
    HelloWorld(); // Declares the constructor
  };
```

Hello.cpp:

```
#include "Hello.hpp"
#include <stdio>

HelloWorld ::
HelloWorld()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World\n";
}
```

Now I can make a change to the `HelloWorld` constructor and not worry about changing the header file.  Because if the header file changes, all the source files that include `Hello.hpp` will need to be recompiled.

**Edit 1: Reducing "HelloWorld::"**
You can remove the `HelloWorld::` part by incorporating a `using` statement:

```
#include "Hello.hpp"
#include <stdio>

using HelloWorld;

HelloWorld()
{
  std::cout << "Hello Mars\n";
}
```

Comment: So, how is implementation inside cpp file different that what I presented?  I'm confused.

Comment: did you answer the OP's question?

Comment: @AB_: I hope I answered the OP's question, but there is some ambiguity about what the OP is asking about:  constructors, method implementations, scope resolution operator, or free standing functions.

Comment: The using statement is strange to me.  My compiler got an error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'HelloWorld'

Answer (score 0):

If this is a class member method then no, there is no way (apart from impractical showcase-only magic like *don't put ; in .h but finish class definition in .cpp*) to avoid class specification.